# Portfolio Jquery presentation

Tags: jquery, grid, portfolio

I need to know what is the plug-in or the jQuery method to achieve this :

http://www.michellecandraw.com/

I'd like to recreate something that way, with the "grid" presentation (I know) and the "sliding div" once you've clicked one of the projects.

If someone has a link for examples, or can help with a small jsfiddle I'd be really glad, I can improve and experiment it myself later then :)

Thanks in advance for your help !
Rom

Comment: Did you even try checking the source code of the site before asking?

Comment: Actually yes, when toggling it opens a "magic door wrap" which I failed to find on Google :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [MixItUp 2](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) .Code can be found [here](https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup).

Comment: Actually the "grid" presentation is not my problem, here I mostly want to find how to make the details of the project slide when you click on a thumbnail.

It is some kind of slideToggle method but a little bit more complex :)